# Styled-components is not working with react

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, styling

I install styled components in my react project. but when I am styling using styled-components styling does not work. Is there any more additional setting doing to work with styled components?Plz help

> yarn add styled-components

Navbar.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Container = styled.div`
  height: '60px';
  background-color: 'black';
`;

const Navbar = () => {
  return <Container>nav</Container>;
};

export default Navbar;
```

package.json:-

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.15"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are writing styled components in the wrong way. Write styled-components CSS as like as normal css. You don't need to put CSS value in string quotation (" ").

```
const Container = styled.div`
  height: 60px;
  background-color: black;
`;
```